# Is there a covariance MLE which takes into account independence relationships?

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, independence

In the extreme case where all of the components of an $M$-variate observation are pairwise independent from each other, a multivariate normal distribution can be decomposed into the product of $M$ univariate normal distributions. For example, $$p \left( X_{1},X_{2},X_{3};[\mu_{1},\mu_{2},\mu_{3}]^{T},\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\sigma_{1} & 0 & 0\\
0 & \sigma_{2} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \sigma_{3}\end{array}\right]\right)=\prod_{i=1}^{3}\ p(X_{i};\mu_{i},\sigma_{i}).$$
The sample complexity of a univariate distribution is less than that of a full-covariance $M$-variate normal distribution, and thus fewer observations are required to get a good approximation of this model, since only univariate distributions must be estimated.

With zero-mean observations $\{x^{(1)},\cdots,x^{(N)}\}$, the covariance MLE for the case where *the covariance matrix is isotropic (i.e. all observation components -- denoted with subscripts -- are pairwise independent)* is simply $\hat{\Sigma}=\mathrm{diag}(\hat{\sigma}_{1,}\hat{\sigma}_{2},\cdots,\hat{\sigma}_{M})$ where $\hat{\sigma}_{i}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\left(x_{i}^{(j)}\right)^{2}$. This pairwise independence is represented as zeros in the *precision matrix* $\Sigma^{-1}$, which is diagonal when $\Sigma$ is diagonal. As mentioned above, this is identical to (i.e. gives the same result as) separately estimating $M$ univariate distributions, and taking their product.

My question is: In the *in between* case, where there is some (not fully connected) dependency graph $\mathcal{G}$ between observation components, what does the covariance MLE look like then? As a specific example, if we say that $X_{1},X_{2}\perp X_{3}$, then the precision matrix must always have the form $$\Sigma^{-1} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\lambda_{11} & \lambda_{12} & 0\\
\lambda_{21} & \lambda_{22} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \lambda_{33}\end{array}\right].$$ 
Therefore, what would the decomposition, and the covariance (or inverse covariance) MLE look like for a normal distribution such as the following? :
$$ p\left(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3};[\mu_{1},\mu_{2},\mu_{3}]^{T},\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\lambda_{11} & \lambda_{12} & 0\\
\lambda_{21} & \lambda_{22} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \lambda_{33}\end{array}\right]^{-1}\right)$$
For a given number of observations, the MLE should give the same result as the decomposed version of the pdf represented by $\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: @Mark, say if there was such a representation, why would you want to use it? Independent case leads to easy computation, but depending on $\mathcal{G}$ the computational complexity can be the same as without any structure assumptions. I am asking purely out of curiosity.

Comment: This sounds like an eigen-decomposition of the covariance matrix would be the way to go.  You can always represent a $M$ dimensional normal as a translated, rotated, and scaled combination of independent standard normals.  Translation does not affect covariance, and scaling does not affect independence/correlations, so you could just examine the rotation matrix, which is given by the matrix of normalised eigenvectors.

Comment: @Mark What do you mean by "sample complexity" and what justifies your conclusion that "fewer samples" are needed for estimation in the diagonal case?

Comment: @whuber - Sample complexity, roughly speaking, is the number of samples required in order to estimate the model in a "probably approximately correct" sense.  The larger the hypothesis space is (larger for an M-variate Normal distribution than for a univariate Normal distribution), the more samples will be required to achieve the same amount of "approximate correctness" to the same probability.  But, in the case of conditional independence relationships, the hypothesis space size is actually smaller than for the case where no independence assumptions are made (i.e. full-covariance matrix).

Comment: @whuber - sorry, I meant to say 'number of observations', and not 'number of samples'.  (edited original post to reflect this -- was a minute too late to edit my previous comment :( )

Comment: @Mark If I understand correctly, then, what you are asking for is the MLE when you assume that certain entries in the covariance matrix are necessarily zero.  But isn't the answer to that question routine (even trivial)?  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you looked at [graphical lasso](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/glasso/)?

Comment: @whuber If I'm not mistaken, conditional independence implies zeroes in the *precision* matrix, not the covariance matrix.  @probabilityislogic You may be right - I'll see what I can figure out.  I guess that an incremental MLE would also require updating the eigenvectors at each step.

Comment: @Mark The point is that, whatever you mean by "conditional independence," it's a set of constraints on the parameters in the full MLE.  The resulting MLE is obtained by optimizing the likelihood subject to those constraints.  If you parameterize the problem in terms of the coefficients of the precision matrix (and the vector of means), your constraints are simple set-to-zero ones.

Comment: @whuber I updated the question to be a bit more explicit.  It would be helpful to me if you (or anyone) could elaborate in an answer, explaining for the example I mention at the end of the question, how one would derive and write the covariance or precision-matrix MLE (also, is there an incremental form?).